# Pregmatch issue

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following function. in this function I want to add slash('/') to check but when I add / then it didn't work or show error.

```
public function alpha_dash_space($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9_\n\r%$#., ])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

Comment: "_but when I add / then it didn't work or show error. _" *What* didn't work and *what* was the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just escape it:

```
return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9_\n\r%$#., \/])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

or change regex delimiter:

```
return ( ! preg_match("~^([-a-z0-9_\n\r%$#., /])+$~i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

You could simplify like:

```
return preg_match("~^[-\w\n\r%$#., /]+$/", $str);
```